Is there a way to save the Node REPL's commands?
Is there a way to save the Node REPL's commands to a file, to use later or share with others?

Please check if the Q&A already exists on the site before posting.

I'm unclear about the downvotes on this question. It is appropriately marked as a duplicate which leads others to an existing question. The downvotes, however, I understand are there to signal an issue with the question. I don't see one. If anything, having the question worded this unique way increases the likelihood that I can turn up something in google search that leads me to the original. Am I missing something?

Yes, there is. The .save command saves "all evaluated commands in this REPL session to a file."
> const sum = (first, second) => first + second
undefined
> sum(1, 2)
3
> .save sum.js
Session saved to: sum.js

Here's the file we made:
const sum = (first, second) => first + second
sum(1, 2)

You can load it back with .load:
> .load sum.js
const sum = (first, second) => first + second
sum(1, 2)
3

Type .help in the REPL for more information.

This is awesome! I never knew this!
